# How to pass file name and size as query parameter in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sharp

The idea is to pass a query that contends the filename and the size as the following:

```
localhost:3000/images?filename=myImage&width=100&height=100
```

First I want to find out how to get the images from the image folder
Second use them to resize the image.
And finally, write the file in a new folder call upload.
I am trying with the following code for now but I am stuck and need some help to continue:
I start refactoring the code and now I have a utilities.ts file with the following code:

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

// accessing the images
let getAccessToFiles = (path: string): boolean => {
    try {
        fs.access(path)
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}

let getFilesName = (
  imageToResize: string,
  width: number | null,
  height: number | null
): string => {
  let filename = imageToResize;
  if (width) {
    filename += `width${width}`;
  }
  if (height) {
    filename += `height${height}`;
    }
    
    return `${filename}.jpg`
};    

export { getAccessToFiles, getFilesName };
```

**Now I just create the conversion like this:**

```
import express, { Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import path from "path";
import sharp from "sharp";
import { getAccessToFiles, getFilesName } from "../../utils/utilities";
const resizeImages: Router = Router();
const app = express();

// access the images
const importImages = path.resolve(__dirname, "images");
// add the output file
const exportImages = path.resolve(__dirname, "uploads");

// allowing our application to parse json input
app.use(express.json());

resizeImages.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const resizeImage = async (
    imageName: string,
    width: number | null,
    height: number | null
  ): Promise<string> => {
    const resizedImageName = getFilesName(imageName, width, height);
    try {
      await sharp(`${importImages}${imageName}.jpg`)
        .resize(width, height)
        .jpeg()
        .toFile(`${importImages}${resizedImageName}`);      
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err});
    }      
    return resizedImageName;
    };
    
    return res.send(resizeImage)
});

export default resizeImages;
```

And finally have the following error: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received function resizeImage

Comment: first you are passing directory as file instead of filename, so it should be `sharp(importImages+filename)` (same applies for export code) second I see lots of bad practice, like using `await` with `then&catch` and `res.send` should be called at end of function.

Answer (score 1):

express puts the query params in a prop called `query`, so in the OP code:  `req.query.filename`, `req.query.width`, and `req.query.height`.

More plausible (not tested) version of the OP code would look like this...

```
// presuming a query looks like "?filename=myImage&width=100&height=100"

const importImages = './images';   // note the removal of the trailing '/'
const exportImages = './uploads';

resizeImages.get('/', (req, res) => {    // note the suggested change in route name
  // note that res.send() moved to become the last promise in the chain
  const fileIn = `${importImages}/${req.query.filename}`;
  const fileOut = `${exportImages}/${req.query.filename}`;
  // note the construction of a complete input and output file specs
  const params = {
    width: req.query.width,
    height: req.query.height,
    fit: 'contain',
    background: { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0, alpha: 0.5 }
  };
  return sharp(fileIn)
    .resize(params).toBuffer().then(data => {
      fs.writeFile(fileOut, data);
    }).then(() => {
      return res.send('done');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello @danh and thank you for the quick response. I do try this solution and in the console, it returns [Error: Input file is missing] and the browser returns an empty object {}

Comment: It sounds like the input file spec isn’t right. Confirm that ‘./images/myImage’ is present. That path is relative to the express app route and the extension needs to be exactly correct, also.  Try hard coding the input file until you get that right, then test the rest.

Comment: Hello @danh I just try to refactor my code in a more modular way. Thank you.